# Make a checkbox checked when a radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have this set of radio buttons, let's say

```
radio 1
radio 2
radio 3
radio 4
```

and a checkbox;

```
checkbox 1
```

What I wanted to achieve is when I click either radio 1 or radio 3 the checkbox 1 will be checked. If the checkbox is checked and when you click either radio 2 or radio 4, the checkbox will be unchecked.

I already implemented some code for it, but it has this glitch that when I click radio 1 it'll check the checkbox, but when I click radio 3 it'll uncheck the checkbox.

Well supposedly, when I click radio 1 it'll check and even if I'll click radio 3, it shouldn't uncheck the checkbox.

here's my code:

```
jQuery('#radio1 input:radio, #radio3 input:radio').click(function(){
    var checkbox = jQuery('#checkbox1');
    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML CODE:**

```
Radio1 :<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"/><br>
Radio2 :<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"/><br>
Radio3 :<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"/><br>
Radio4 :<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio"/><br>
Checkbox :<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
```

**jQuery CODE:**

```
 jQuery('#radio1 , #radio3').click(function(){      
jQuery('#checkbox1').attr('checked', true);   
 });        
jQuery('#radio2 , #radio4').click(function(){      
 jQuery('#checkbox1').attr('checked', false);  
 });
```

**Live DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hQbpZ/

Comment: `attr` => 'checked' VS `prop` => true.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
   var checkbox = $('#checkbox1');
   switch(this.id){
      case 'radio1':
      case 'radio3':
      checkbox.attr('checked', true);
      break;

      case 'radio2':
      case 'radio4':
      checkbox.attr('checked', false);
      break;
   }
});
```

Comment: There's no distinction in the logic you've established.. I think instead of copying and pasting the function, the first function should statically set checked to true or false, and the second function should statically set the checked attribute to the opposite of the first function. Currently, your code will just continue to toggle the checkboxes, regardless of what the user really clicks.

Comment: Indeed it better resembles the intended solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#radio1, #radio3').click(function(){
    jQuery('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
});

jQuery('#radio2, #radio4').click(function(){
    jQuery('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Though you can do it in many other ways. One more example:

```
jQuery(':radio').change(function(){
    var toCheck = this.id == 'radio1' || this.id == 'radio3'; 
    jQuery('#checkbox1').prop('checked', toCheck);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/FFBnj/4/) (markup was taken from @Matrix)

Comment: @Jetoox. oops. then `checkbox1` is a bad name... :) fixed thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work man. I tried it, well apparently you missed the "#radio1 input:radio" but nevertheless it doesn't work

Comment: @Jetoox. no, you probably have problems with the HTML-DOM. `input:radio` was a mistake.

Comment: i see. pardon me. im not so well versed in HTML-DOM. my bad. :)

Comment: @Jetoox. You can see the demo